# How to access a single field of the logstash metadata event?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logastash 7.6 with the output-jdbc plugin, but I get an error and I understand that it is because in the event it sends me all the fields to be indexed that are part of @metadata.
Probe just putting the event name without @ and it works for me.

How can I get a single field within a @metada set?

ERROR:

```
ERROR logstash.outputs.jdbc - JDBC - Exception. Not retrying {:exception=>#, :statement=>"UPDATE table SET estate = 'P' WHERE codigo = ? ", :event=>"{\"properties\":{\"rangoAltura1\":null,\"rangoAltura2\":null,\"codigo\":\"DB_001\",\"rangoAltura3\":null,\"descrip\":\"CARLOS PEREZ\",\"codigo\":\"106\",\"rangoAltura5\":null,\"active\":true},\"id\":\"DB_001_555\"}"}
```

My .conf:

```
statement => ["UPDATE table SET estate = 'A' WHERE entidad = ? ","%{[@metadata][miEntidad]}"]
```

{[@metadata][miEntidad]} -----> map['entidad_temp'] = event.get('entidad')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the output jdbc plugin [README](https://github.com/theangryangel/logstash-output-jdbc#configuration-options) you have it set correctly/

Maybe try the following as a work-around:

`statement => ["UPDATE table SET estate = 'A' WHERE entidad = ? ","[@metadata][miEntidad]"]`